# Given a function with several logical steps, each step requiring reference to N shared objects, how can this function be optimally deconstructed?

Tags: function, theory

When using the coding practice of decomposing functions into smaller functions which each do "one logical thing", it appears as though the approach sometimes leads to code which is hard to debug.

As an example, imagine I have the following code:

```
Function Foo(Class1* p1, Class2* p2, Class3* p3)
{
   Function InitializeStuff(Class1* p1, Class2* p2, Class3* p3)
   Function DoFirstBlockOfWork(Class1* p1, Class2* p2, Class3* p3)
   Function DoSecondBlockOfWork(Class1* p1, Class2* p2, Class3* p3)
   Function FinishStuff(Class1* p1, Class2* p2, Class3* p3)

}
```

In this example, there are 3 object references needed in each logical block.  Now, when the debugger stops inside one of these blocks, it is difficult to know where the inputs came from within the code file (especially if not familiar with the codebase).

In this case, there is the added benefit of understanding when reading top-down, but when debugging bottom-up, it seems this method is actually more cumbersome than placing all the functionality in Foo.

So, in the case of a function with highly coupled logical blocks, what is the argument for splitting the functionality into smaller functions?

(Note:  I have been living with the assumption that it's *always* best to deconstruct functions to the smallest logical block.)

Comment: You create a function when you are going to use the same thing multiple times.
Let's say you define a polynomial f(x)=x^2 + 3x +4
and you need the value of the polynomial for x = 3, 4 and 5.
In that case you write the polynomial as it is written and you just call f(3), f(4) and f(5).
But if you need something only once, lets say we need the polynomial just for a single value 7, then we can just write 7*7 + 3*7 + 4inline and we are done.

Comment: I do understand a function is beneficial in cases where code will be re-used.  The question I am asking is, regardless of re-use, why is splitting functions to the smallest logical block a beneficial, and well accepted practice if it causes unnecessary complexity when debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Readability counts. As per the comment by dimm, a use case of functions (or routines, or procedures, etc) is reusability.

So, if you have the same code repeated in multiple places, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) tells you to introduce a function.

Besides of that, a function should be (1) readable and (2) easy to debug (and test, if you do unit testing).

This leads to the rule of thumb of having functions which do one thing. Because they are easier to name, the behaviour is simpler to define and debug, and being shorter you can just glance at the code and identify the meaning.

When you go too far with this approach, however, you get to the point of having a lot of really small functions, and you risk losing the big picture.

My rule of thumb is: if the function doesn't fit a "page" (say, 20-30 lines maximum), it is a candidate for splitting. Only exception to this rule are "list-like" methods, containing large switch/case statements.

Some prefer one big function with comments inside it, but I like more self-commenting code with descriptive function names.

Some others do like smaller functions, with no more than 8 lines of code, but that length is exceedingly short for my taste.

YMMV.